# css animation not able to implement in navigation bar

Tags: html, css

I'm new Html and CSS and trying to create a navigation bar with animation- when I hover on the menu items, the dropdown should appear in a slide down animation. but I'm unable to do so. Can some please guide me how to achieve this.It would be of immense help.I have tried using -

```
webkit-transition: height 2s; /* For Safari 3.1 to 6.0 */
  transition: height 2s;
```

But, nothing is happening.
My Code:

```css
nav ul li a{
   line-height:59px;
  -webkit-transition: background-color 2s;
  -moz-transition: background-color 2s;
  -o-transition: background-color 2s;
  transition: background-color 2s;
}

nav .navbar-nav .nav-item .nav-link:hover, .dropdown:hover .dropbtn{
  background-color: #f1c575;
}

nav .navbar-nav .nav-item .nav-link {
  position: relative;
}

nav .navbar-nav .nav-item .nav-link:hover:after {
content: "";
display: block;
border-left: 10px solid transparent;
border-right: 10px solid transparent;
border-bottom: 10px solid #7B8B93;
position: absolute;
left: 35%;
bottom: 0px;
}

/* Nav Menu Starts */

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #7b8b93;
  width: 100%;
  left: 0;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  z-index: 1;
  -webkit-transition: height 2s; /* For Safari 3.1 to 6.0 */
  transition: height 2s;
}

nav ul li .dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
  height: 300px;
}

.dropdown{
  position: initial;
}


.nav-link:hover + .dropdown .dropdown-content{
  display: block;
}

/* Nav Menu  Ends*/
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">LoGo</a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>

  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
    <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Capabilities</a>
        <div class="dropdown">
          <div class="dropdown-content">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-lg-4">
                <h3 class="ml-3">Products</h3>
                <p class="ml-3"><a class="commerce" href="#">Dr.Commerce</a></p>
              </div>
              <div class="col-lg-8 services">
                <h3>Capabilities</h3>
                <ul class="list-inline">
                  <li class="list-inline-item">
                    <img src="./images/twitter-xxl.png" width="60" height="67" alt="New York">
                  </li>
                  <li class="list-inline-item">
                    <img src="./images/instagram-xxl.png" width="60" height="67" alt="New York">
                  </li>

                </ul>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: I can see the animation on Firefox https://i.imgur.com/pvZQNvf.gif , can you indicate in which browser you need it to work? Safari maybe.

Comment: It's for chrome @DanielDoblado

Answer (score 0):

Well the problem you are having is that you added the transition effect but actually there is no transition going on, at least the way you want.

So I made the following changes:-

```css
nav ul li a{
   line-height:59px;
  -webkit-transition: background-color 2s;
  -moz-transition: background-color 2s;
  -o-transition: background-color 2s;
  transition: background-color 2s;
}

nav .navbar-nav .nav-item .nav-link:hover, .dropdown:hover .dropbtn{
  background-color: #f1c575;
}

nav .navbar-nav .nav-item .nav-link {
  position: relative;
}

nav .navbar-nav .nav-item .nav-link:hover:after {
content: "";
display: block;
border-left: 10px solid transparent;
border-right: 10px solid transparent;
border-bottom: 10px solid #7B8B93;
position: absolute;
left: 35%;
bottom: 0px;
}

/* Nav Menu Starts */

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  height: 140px; // added this line here
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #7b8b93;
  width: 100%;
  left: 0;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  z-index: 1;
  -webkit-transition: height 2s; /* For Safari 3.1 to 6.0 */
  transition: height 2s;
}

.dropdown-content:hover{
  display: block;
  height: 300px;
}

.dropdown{
  position: initial;
}


.nav-link:hover + .dropdown .dropdown-content{
  display: block;
}

/* Nav Menu  Ends*/
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">LoGo</a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>

  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
    <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Capabilities</a>
        <div class="dropdown">
          <div class="dropdown-content">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-lg-4">
                <h3 class="ml-3">Products</h3>
                <p class="ml-3"><a class="commerce" href="#">Dr.Commerce</a></p>
              </div>
              <div class="col-lg-8 services">
                <h3>Capabilities</h3>
                <ul class="list-inline">
                  <li class="list-inline-item">
                    <img src="./images/twitter-xxl.png" width="60" height="67" alt="New York">
                  </li>
                  <li class="list-inline-item">
                    <img src="./images/instagram-xxl.png" width="60" height="67" alt="New York">
                  </li>

                </ul>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

This is I think the problem is and I tried to point it out. Hope this is the solution.